# Expand monitor without native shortcut Win+P

Tags: multiple-monitors

is there any way to expand the monitor using keyboard shortcuts (other than a native "win+p" function) in windows 10?
Example: I configure the F1 key, and when I click on it the monitor expands, and when I click again it returns to normal, displaying only 1 monitor.

Comment: Hello, why not just rebind the native Win + P to F1?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest below a method for doing this by using two different
shortcuts, one to extend and one to unextend the desktop.

Create two `.bat` files containing each one of the following
command-lines.

To extend the desktop :

```
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /extend
```

To unextend the desktop :

```
C:\Windows\System32\DisplaySwitch.exe /internal
```

Right-click each file and select
*Send to > Desktop (create shortcut)*.
This will create two icons on the desktop.

Right-click each icon in turn, rename as needed, and add a
key shortcut.
If you choose for example F1 and F2, then one key will extend
the desktop and the other will undo it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this worked.
One last question: is there any way to not need to play the ".bat" shortcuts on the desktop, but rather put them in some specific folder on the hd?
because the functions only work when the shortcut is on the desktop. If I put it in some other folder, the keyboard shortcuts don't work.

Comment: No, the shortcut feature is unique to the desktop. Or you could use AutoHotKey for this without using `.bat` files.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).